# Change username in spring security when logged in

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, authentication, spring-security

I want to change username while this user logged in system. I implemented my own crypt algorithm and cannot get real password to make a new authentication and put it in

```
Authentication authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(principal, credentials);
```

Comment: This should answer your issue. http://stackoverflow.com/a/14174404/1251350

Answer (score 7):

After Logging in, you can change your username and password with this code:

```js
Collection<SimpleGrantedAuthority> nowAuthorities = 
  (Collection<SimpleGrantedAuthority>)SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
                                                           .getAuthentication()
                                                           .getAuthorities();
UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = 
  new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password, nowAuthorities);

SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
```

Comment: that will be changed on oauth as well?

Comment: Yes. To make quite sure if your username is changed or not after you changed username with those codes I recommended you, Just use this code SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName(); to get username and you will be able to see the changed usename.

Comment: No, it didn't I tested today the access token still didn't changed in DB!

Comment: Yes, To make quite sure if oauth is changed or not after you changed username using my codes that I recommended, Just use this code "SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName()" to see the changed username.

Comment: Which DB do you use?

Comment: I checked the DB, i used postgres!

Comment: I don't know why I suddenly may have the same problem as yours, so I changed the codes above a little bit to solve the problem so just try it. It seems like we need to define three things 'username', 'password' and 'role' to get authority on spring security.

Comment: And I don't think this problem is related to database. Did you override UserDetailsService in Spring Security?

Comment: Sure, but why you asking about UserdetailsService ? Because its token related thing!

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood.

Answer (score 4):

```
Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        User userDetails = (User) authentication.getPrincipal();
        userDetails.setUsername("newusername");
```

My class User implements UserDetails. This solution is simple and it works.